# What kind of advantage are ethnic Indians and the Republic of India expecting from Rishi Sunak?

Tags: united-kingdom, india

Indians are celebrating Rishi Sunak's appointment as the PM.

Why are they celebrating?

Being an ethnic Indian and a Hindu, what kind of advantage do ethnic Indians in the UK and the Republic of India expect from Rishi Sunak?

Comment: There are more than 3 million South Asian people in the UK, it is an enormously diverse group.

Comment: The title question and the body are subtly different.  The title asks "what advantages **can** they expect", and the body  "What advantages **do** they expect".  Which question are you asking.

Comment: Is it just me or does this have an icky Fifth Column-ish feel to it?  VTC

Answer (score 2):

India (and Pakistan, Bangladesh and Myanmar) used to be ruled by the British. The effects of that were a complex mixture of positive and negative, but in summary, the British *definitely* did better out of it than the South Asians. South Asians in the UK have faced discrimination, which is currently less blatant than it used to be, but still real.

Now a British Indian has become Prime Minister. This undermines any "justifications" for discrimination and racism and demonstrates a large step towards true equality for everyone.

Comment: A single prime minister does not undermine any of the "justifications" especially considering the recent turmoil in the position.